# Why doesn't MatchResult have a method for named groups?

Tags: java, regex

`Matcher` implements `MatchResult`, which "contains query methods used to determine the results of a match against a regular expression." Surprisingly, although `group()`, `group(int)` and `groupCount()` are available through the `MatchResult` interface, `group(String)` is not.

Is this an oversight, or was it left out Java 7 for compatibility reasons? If it's for backwards compatibility, couldn't that have been resolved with a default method in Java 8?

Comment: @Sanjeev did you even read the question? I'm specifically asking about the *MatchResult interface*.

Comment: Agreed .. retracted my close vote

Comment: Java's regex API is so non-intuitive, IMO. I can't believe this method still doesn't exist in Java 12!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `MatchResult` interface has been added with Java 1.5, while `group(String)` is a Java 1.7 addition.

Adding `group(String)` to the interface would have been a breaking change, because any other implementation outside of Java's `Matcher` would not compile. Java designers generally avoid interface changes like that, so they did not do it.

A more interesting question is why they have not done it in Java 1.8, which allows specifying default implementations for interfaces. My guess is that there is no good default for such implementation, apart from throwing a "not implemented" exception.

Comment: Throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` seems like a reasonable option. And it's not unprecedented either - see `Iterator.remove()` (though I realize that case was common even prior to 1.8).

Comment: @shmosel `Iterator.remove()` has been marked as an optional operation, and it was easy to explain (not every iterator allows modification). It would be more difficult to justify making `group(String)` optional without invoking "historical reasons". I wouldn't be surprised that Oracle has simply forgot to add the method, though, and that they would add it at some later time.

Comment: Still doesn't exist in 2020. Writing code in Java (up to 12, at least) after C# is like going back in time.

Comment: @JoshM. To me, coding in Java felt like going back in time ever since Java and C# took different approaches to implementing generics. This has also sealed the fate of Java's LINQ implementation.

Comment: I totally agree @dasblinkenlight. There are so many things "missing" in Java.

Comment: They are [talking](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7032377) about adding it (as of mid-2022). Hopefully we’ll finally get it.